# Array issues in Arduino Uno's ino

Tags: c++, arrays, random, arduino, arduino-uno

I am trying out Arduino programming for the first time and am having issues with an array that causes two undesirable behaviors depending on the position of said array in the code. The array must be used in a function called ''writeMenuChoicePokemon'' in order to change random integers into random strings with the names of the available monsters.

My first attempt was to put

```
String array_names[21] =
    {
    "Bulbasaur","Charmander","Squirtle","Ekans","Pikachu","Jigglypuff","Zubat","Venonat","Meowth","Psyduck","Mankey","Abra",
    "Tentacool","Geodude","Magnemite","Gastly","Onix","Hitmonlee","Rhyhorn","Jynx","Dragonite"
    };
```

into the function itself and use for example

```
lcd.print(array_names[pokemon1])
```

with pokemon1 being a random integer, but when the random ints are between 14 and 20 the result is an empty string. What can be causing this?

My second attempt was to put array_names as a global variable, but my program stops responding to my button inputs and doesn't show anything at all on the screen except for the random Pokémon. Could this be due to lack of memory? Where is the proper position to declare an array used in the main loop?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you add a link to the full source, I don't think it is due to a lack of memory.

Comment: Sure, here's the full code between the loop() and the LCD printing function: codeshare.io/rT0RB (I am sorry if the code looks messy, this is very much a learning experience. The array is on line 369 and the state calling the array is on line 96) If there's anything else you'd want to see, I'll add it to the document.

EDIT: creating the Stadium class in a state completely prevents the code from behaving normally even before it reaches that state. It really seems like a memory problem.

Comment: You need to post a link to your **full** source as @Dinal24 requested if you want to get a helpful answer. A shot in the dark: perhaps declared your variable TIME as an 'int', and not, as you should, as a 'long int'. Unless we see your full source, there is no other way to ask